# Purpose of the anchor map, Lie algebroid

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, sheaf-theory, lie-algebroids

Let $X$ be a scheme. A Lie algebroid $L$ on $X$ is a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module equipped with a morphism of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules $\sigma:L\to \mathcal{T}_X$ the tangent sheaf, and a Lie bracket $[-,-]:L\otimes_\Bbb C L\to L$, such that:

- The Lie bracket $[-,-]$ commutes with $\sigma$,
- for $a,b\in L, f\in \mathcal{O}_X$, we have $[a,fb]=f[a,b]+\sigma(a)(f)b$.

---

1. a) What does it mean to say $a,b\in L$, does this mean $a,b$ are global sections of $L$?
2. b) What does the bracket mean? Is this also $a\otimes b \mapsto ab-ba$ where $a,b$ are global sections of $L$?
3. What does the so-called anchor map $\sigma$ do, and why is it named this?

Comment: 1) This mean that $a,b$ are sections on a unspecified open subset $U$. Everything should be true for any $U$ and compatible with restrictions. 2) The bracket is part of the structure of the Lie algebroid. $L$ is not just a sheaf, this is a sheaf with a specified $\sigma$ and a specified bracket (just like a group is a set with a specified multiplication). $ab-ba$ does not mean anything if $L$ is not a ring. But if it is, it could be an example (among many others) of bracket. $L$ is not necessarily a ring though.

Comment: @Roland Just to confirm, we are giving a $\Bbb C$-linear Lie bracket $[-,-]$ to $L(X)$ , i.e. the global sections of this sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. We are also giving this structure for each $L(U)$, where $U$ is some open subset?

Comment: We are forming a sheaf of $\Bbb C$-Lie algebras which are also $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules (among other things like possessing the anchor and compatibility)?

What did you mea in regard to being compatible with restrictions?

Comment: Yes, the Lie bracket structure is on any open set, and should be compatible with the restriction, in other words $[a,b]_{|U}=[a_{|U},b_{|U}]$. This is why this is a map between sheaves $L\otimes L\rightarrow L$. And similarly, $[a,fb]_{|U}=f_{|U}[a_{|U},b_{|U}]+\sigma(a_{|U})(f_{|U})b_{|U}$.

Comment: @Roland Thanks so much, that makes things much more clear. Do you know of a resource that covers this in so much detail (in the same setting as above)? All four references that I've seen are written very unclearly (from the perspective of a newbie).

Comment: No sorry I don't. I never seen a Lie algebroid before. It is just that I am accustomed to the sheaf language.